# cURL send cookies

Tags: azure, curl, azure-active-directory

This might be a long shot, but I have the following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/abc123/oauth2/authorize?
&resource=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com
&client_id=12345
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=localhost/response
&response_mode=fragment
&state=
&nonce=678910
&prompt=none
```

When I access it in my browser, it returns an access token.  This is because my browser is logged into the Azure Active Directory.

Instead of via the browser, I want to get the response via CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This almost works, except for the following error:

```
A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD
```

I know you can send Cookies using CURL, but how would I send the Cookie that Azure AD is expecting? I'm assuming its an existing browser Cookie somewhere but I'm struggling to think of a way of figuring out what the silent sign-in is expecting.

I have full access to the access token from the initial Azure AD login (as that is done through my app) but I don't know what the silent sign in wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't use cURL instead of the browser. You must redirect the browser so the user can sign in, go through MFA if necessary, sign in to their org local AD.

Try to see the [sample code](https://developer.byu.edu/docs/consume-api/use-api/oauth-20/oauth-20-php-sample-code). The sample of implicit flow is too old, but what you want is similar to the function "getAuthorizationCode()".

You could obtain access token with [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

```
<?php

$clientId = "";
$clientSecret = "";
$fullurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$post_params = array(
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
    "client_id" => $clientId,
    "client_secret" => $clientSecret,
    "scope" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
);

$ch = curl_init($fullurl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
echo json_decode($response)->access_token; // access_token
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.